# Rails: How to get the last message creation time of a given user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, active-record-query

User can have multiple messages:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :messages, :foreign_key => "publisher_id"
end
```

To get the latest message time I do:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def last_message_time
    last_message = messages.max{ |m1, m2| m1.created_at <=> m2.created_at }
    last_message ? last_message.created_at : nil
  end
end
```

For some reason, I'm sure that there is a better way to do this.

How would you do this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a short version:

```
# Ruby < 2.3.0
def last_message_time
  messages.order(:created_at).last.try(:created_at)
end

# Ruby >= 2.3.0
def last_message_time
  messages.order(:created_at).last&.created_at
end
```

**Update (thx @mnort9):**
Updated for Ruby > 2.3.0

Comment: This will give the first message, not the latest. Otherwise, nice - didn't know about `try`

Comment: I think it should be `last` rather than `first`!

Comment: Btw normally I'm not a fan of `try` because it sometimes results in ugly and unreadable code, but this is the killer usage for it.

Comment: @ream88: I agree that `try` is not very readable, but still, it's a nice method!

Comment: You can also use the safe navigation operator `last&.created_at`

Comment: Yes @mnort9, thats the way to go with Ruby 2.3+.

Answer (score 4):

At the very least, you can get the database to do the sorting for you.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def last_message_time
    last_message = messages.find(:last, :order => :created_at)
    last_message ? last_message.created_at : nil
  end
end
```

Comment: OP said the last message, so shouldn't the order by DESC ? This gives the oldest published message not the most recent.

Comment: No - I'm `find`ing the `:last`. This generates SQL like: `SELECT * FROM "messages" WHERE ("messages".publisher_id = 5) ORDER BY created_at DESC, created_at DESC LIMIT 1`

Comment: You are right! But can you apply find to messages which is a collection and not an active record object ?

Comment: Yes. I tested it on my own app.

Comment: @Ocaj: See here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#tt-em-collection-em-find-tt

Comment: @Chowlett Thank you for your answers :-). One more question regarding code organization. Would it be better to move this method within `class Message` and call it like `messages.last_messsage_time` ?

Comment: No. Why? Because `messages` is not an instance of `class Message`. You _could_ define it just on the `messages` association: `has_many :messages do def last_time ... end` - see [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_many#461-User-a-block-to-extend-your-associations)